# Effect of duplicated row on singular values and vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-optimization

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a $n\times n$ matrix with Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{U}\mathbf{S}\mathbf{V}$ and $\mathbf{a}_1$ be the first row of $\mathbf{A}$. What can we say about the Singular Values and Vectors of $\mathbf{B}$ based on the SVD of $\mathbf{A}$?
\begin{align}
\mathbf{B}=\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{A}\\\mathbf{a}_1
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}

Comment: $B$ is a rank-one update of $A$, so you can use the various results for that case, see for example https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/177007/338593

Comment: Yes. There is a numerical solution. Is there a closed form solution for this particular case?

Answer (score 0):

The singular values of $\sigma_i(B)$ are given by
$$\sigma_i(B)^2=\lambda_i(B^*B)=\lambda_i(BB^*).$$

We have that
$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{B}\mathbf{B}^*=\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^*&\mathbf{A}a_1^*\\\mathbf{a}_1\mathbf{A}^*&a_1a_1^*
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$ is a $(n+1)\times (n+1)$ block matrix. The [Cauchy's interlacing theorem](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.2004.11920060) gives the inequality $$\lambda_{n+1}(\mathbf{B}\mathbf{B}^*)\leq \lambda_n(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^*)\leq \cdots \leq \lambda_2(\mathbf{B}\mathbf{B}^*)\leq \lambda_1(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^*)\leq  \lambda_1(\mathbf{B}\mathbf{B}^*).$$

**Remark:** You can find related results searching for "\(A^*A+a_1^*a_1\)  with \(a_1\) a row matrix singular values" on SearchOnMath. Like this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382142/interlacing-theorem-on-singular-values#answer-1382292) which gave me some glimpses on what I wrote above.

Comment: In particular, $B$ has rank $\leq n$, so $\lambda_{n+1}(BB^*) = 0$.